# Resetting an angularjs model; ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show, angularjs-ng-show

I'm trying to determine why calling my`$scope.reset()` method does not work as I hoped.  What I want to accomplish is: once the Reset button is clicked, the `values` object is re-initialized and its `theState` field is set to `'one'`.  This should cause the div with `id='one'` to be shown and it's 2 sibling to be hidden.

What actually happens when Reset is clicked is that all three `div` elements are hidden until I click one of the buttons labeled One,Two,Three.  I'm *assuming* that the reason this fails is that the actual object to which `ng-show` is bound is changing in `$scope.reset()` - but I don't know how to get the view to react as I want.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <input type="button" ng-click="values.theState='one'" value="One"/>
  <input type="button" ng-click="values.theState='two'" value="Two"/>
  <input type="button" ng-click="values.theState='three'" value="Three"/>

  <div id="one" ng-show="values.theState=='one'">
    This is div=1
  </div>
  <div id="two" ng-show="values.theState=='two'">
    This is div=2
  </div>
  <div id="tre" ng-show="values.theState=='three'">
    This is div=3
  </div>

  <input type="button" ng-click="reset()" value="Reset"/>           
</div>
```

AngularJS:

```
<script>
  var app = angular.module("app", []);
  app.controller("AppCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.values = {
      theState: 'one'
    };

    $scope.reset = function() {
      $scope.values = {};
      $scope.value.theState = 'one';                    
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: See if you can recreate the broken function here: http://plnkr.co/edit/4zkHRl8eTBvmzvJBRNkH?p=preview

Comment: Found it.  I was rewriting a single-page app in angular, added a pair of `div`s to toggle on and off and, thru copy-and-paste, neglected to remove the old `id`s from the HTML.  Been staring at that one defect for a week.

Comment: You should probably delete this question since the problem was not in relation to the code posted. Congrats on finding your problem.

Comment: I've flagged it for moderator deletion.  Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an 's' in your reset function:

```
$scope.values.theState = 'one';
```

Comment: Ah... I tried to recreate the problem in my actual code with a simple example and mistyped.  Your answer certainly fixes my example issue - thanks - but something else is going on in the app I'm writing.  I'll have to do a bit more playing around to recreate.